# interesting task for Fast enumeration protocol

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

How is known to support FE protocol, I must implement method:
– countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:

But it method is do not knows what type of object I want enumerate. For example my custom object has two arrays:

```
NSArray* names - for NSString objects; 
NSArray* sites - for NSURL objects;
```

Now I want enumerate them:

```
for( NSString* name in myObj )
{

}
```

and

```
for( NSURL* url in myObj )
{

}
```

Can I do that  – countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count: define what kind of objects it must enumerate? (Without using additional class attributes :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Fast enumeration can only support one type of enumeration per class so you would have to decide which case is more important for you.

However, `NSEnumerator` also supports fast enumeration. So your class could support 2 different enumerators (let's call them `nameEnumerator` and `urlEnumerator`) and the class's users can then use fast enumeration like this:

```
for (NSString *name in [myObj nameEnumerator]) { ... }
for (NSURL *url in [myObj urlEnumerator]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, type information is not available in that way. I can't think of any mainstream language that would allow return type polymorphism in this way, which is what you're asking for.

Why not simply expose the arrays as properties?

```
@interface myObj {
     NSArray *names;
     NSArray *sites;
}
@property(readonly) NSArray *names;
@property(readonly) NSArray *sites;
@end

@implementation myObj
@synthesize names, sites;
@end
```

Then you can do this:

```
for (NSString* name in myObj.names) {

}
for (NSURL* sites in myObj.sites) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that as long as you ensure that only NSStrings are in `names` and only NSURLs in `sites`. You only make a cast with "NSString*" telling the compiler that you know that `names` contains NSString objects. You don't actually enforce that these are only NSString objects. Hope that helped.

Comment: this is not exactly what I need. The problem is in realization enumerating method. I Can not chose in it what type of objects I must to enumerate, because  method do not knows about for what type of objects he was invoked.

Answer (score 0):

for( NSString* name in [myObj names] ) {…}

and

for( NSURL* url in [myObj sites] ) {…}